# Working with Time portion of a DateTime Column in SQL Server2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table in SQL Server 2008 which its name is Table1.
Table1 has a column named CreateDate which its data type is datetime.
Now, I wanna to get records that their createDate field values are more than for instance 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with some datetime functions ,like  [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) functions

e.g : `select dateadd(hh,-1,GETDATE())`

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2008, you should use the built-in `TIME` datetype as much as possible.

If you have a DATETIME column, you can easily convert it to just TIME by using:

```
SELECT CAST(CreateDate AS TIME) FROM Table1
```

That should return just the TIME part of the DATETIME column.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

This will get records that are older than one hour:

```
select * from Table1 where createDate < dateadd(hh, -1, getdate())
```